# MVC JSON AJAX DateTime Format

Tags: ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi I am trying to use AJAX to edit a grid.

First I made model (BPViewModel):

```
 public DateTime Day { get; set; }
```

The Repository:

```
public static IList<BPViewModel> All()
    {
        IList<BPViewModel> result = (IList<BPViewModel>)HttpContext.Current.Session["BloodPressures"];
        //     string id = "2222222222";
        //    id = Session["PHN"].ToString();
        if (result == null)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["BloodPressures"] = result =
                (from bloodpressure in new DALDataContext().BloodPressures
                 select new BPViewModel
                 {
                 .......
                     Day = bloodpressure.Day 
                 }).ToList();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

In the controller I get the data using"

```
  public ActionResult BloodPressure_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
         return Json(BPRepository.All().ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }
```

In the view:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<BPViewModel>()

    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    columns.Bound(p => p.Day).Format("{0:d}");
```

The date is displayed as 1/1/2012; however when I edit it (using Ajax) it shows as Sun Jan 1 00:00:00 PST 2012!!  When I try to update the row, I get "Day is invalid Date.

I tried to use bloodpressure.Day.ToShortDateString(), it did not work.

Any idea how I can convert the date to yyyy,mm,dd?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, here is some reading material on MSDN for date time formatting: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4

That said have you tried something as simple as the following:

```
yourdate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: Thanks, it didn't work; got Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.DateTime' error.

Comment: Then you are already working with a string. Simply use the same formatting with yourstring.Format